# Mysqli and PHP Loop query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to fetch Attendance details of `Employee`.
I have created the Query, and got correct result. But I wanted query to generated using loop.

Details as follows

**Table: Attendance**

Columns: (emp_id,emp_name,dated,present,absent,leave,comment).

For example:

```
/* count December leave */
$sql_l_12="select * from `attendance` where `emp_id`='".$getid."' AND `leave`='1' and MONTH(dated)='12'";
$res_l_12=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_l_12);
$count_l_12= mysqli_num_rows($res_l_12);
```

The above same code i have written for Present and absent.

```
"$sql_l_12": in this l=leave ,12=month(December)

"$sql_p_08": in this p=present ,08=august
```

Therefore

```
3(query) * 12(months)=36 Queries.

36(Queries) * 3(line) = 108 Lines
```

---

I am trying to use some loop or Function, in PHP, so that lines becomes less and more efficient. But getting errors after using loop.

Visit for screenshot http://uploadpie.com/EkSFK

Comment: Why do you have `emp_name` in the `attendance` table? `emp_id` should be a foreign key to the `employee` table, and the name should be there.

Comment: Please provide an example of how exactly the output should look like. Because "Attendance details of Employee" could also mean to just get all the details of your current SQL table. And do you need the data of all users or just one?

Comment: Jo Smo:  I have sent the screenshot in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the month and column values in the query, just use the employee ID. Then sum all the columns grouping by the month.

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(dated) AS month, SUM(`leave`) AS `leave`, SUM(present) AS present, SUM(absent) AS absent
        FROM attendance
        WHERE emp_id = '$getid'
        GROUP BY month";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $results[$row['month']] = $row;
}

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\wamp\www\eye_online\members\ttt.php on line 12

Comment: I've updated my answer to add error checking. What is the error?

Comment: What is the datatype of `emp_id`?

Comment: datatype: varchar

Comment: error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'leave) AS leave, SUM(present) AS present, SUM(absent) AS absent FROM at' at line 1

Comment: datatype for leave,present,absent  is tinyint(1).

Comment: `leave` is a reserved word, it needs to be escaped with backticks. Also, since `emp_id` is a string, `$getid` needs to be in quotes. I assumed it was an integer, since most databases use numbers for IDs.